# Iterative depth-first tree traversal with pre- and post-visit at each node

Tags: algorithm, tree-traversal

Can anyone point me at pseudocode for iterative depth-first tree traversal, where it's possible to do actions on each node at both pre- and post- order?

That is, an action before descent into a node's children, then an action after ascent from the children?

Also, my tree is not binary - each node has 0..n children.

Basically, my case is transforming a recursive traversal, where I do the pre- and post- operations on the current node, either side of the recursion into the children.

Comment: Pretty generic question, with pretty specific requirements ;). What about just asking for hints on an iterative traversal - pre/post ops will than just fit in ;).

Comment: Sounds like 'can anyone show me how to iterate over array and execute function on each element'. What's the problem with iterating it step by step, just as you described?

Comment: Each parent needs to be visited before it's children (pre-operation) then visited once more after it's children (post-operation). We lose that context when we iterate over an array. Easy to do recursively, but it beats me how to do that iteratively.

Comment: Tree traversal is inherently recursive. In converting to an iterative approach, you'll still need to use a stack of your own to be able to track back up the tree.

Comment: I don't know if this applies, but I've done a similar thing for a uni project. Basically it was a program where you can enter a binary formula and it will try to solve it. For this, the formula tree has to be converted multiple times so I made a system where "Walkers" are applied to each node of the tree, from the root down to the leafs. When the walker returns something not null it would replace the node with the returned value. See source code here https://github.com/narrowtux/TIL-project-3/blob/master/src/main/java/de/unikassel/til3/formula/Formula.java#L90

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My plan is to use two stacks. One for pre-order traversal and another one is for post-order traversal.
Now, I run standard iterative DFS (depth-first traversal), and as soon as I `pop` from the "pre" stack i push it in "post" stack.
At the end, my "post" stack will have child node at top and and root at bottom.

```pseudo
treeSearch(Tree root) {
    Stack pre;
    Stack post;
    pre.add(root);
    while (pre.isNotEmpty()) {
        int x = pre.pop();
        // do pre-order visit here on x
        post.add(x);
        pre.addAll(getChildren(x));
    }
    while (post.isNotEmpty()) {
        int y = post.pop();
        // do post-order visit here on y
    }
}
```

`root` will always be traversed last from `post` stack as it will stay at the bottom.

This is simple java code:

```java
public void treeSearch(Tree tree) {
    Stack<Integer> preStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> postStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    preStack.add(tree.root);
    while (!preStack.isEmpty()) {
        int currentNode = preStack.pop();
        // do pre-order visit on current node
        postStack.add(currentNode);
        int[] children = tree.getNeighbours(currentNode);
        for (int child : children) {
            preStack.add(child);
        }
    }

    while (!postStack.isEmpty()) {
        int currentNode = postStack.pop();
        // do post-order visit on current node
    }
}
```

I am assuming this is a tree, so: **no cycle** and **no revisiting** the same node again. But, if we want we can always have a visited array and check against that.

Comment: Seems like this will do the pre-visits on all the node first and then the post-visits, but if the post-visit of a child is needed before the pre-visit of the next sibling, it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this post is several years old, but none of the answers seem to directly answer the question, so I figured I'd write up something somewhat simple.

This assumes an integer indexed graph; but you can certainly adapt it as necessary. The key to doing DFS iteratively and still having pre-order/post-order operations is to NOT just append *every* child at once, but instead, behave exactly as recursive DFS would, which is adding  just one child-node to the stack at a time, and only removing them from the stack once it has finished. I accomplish this in my example by creating a wrapper node with the adjacency list as a stack. Just omit the cycle check if you wish to allow cycles (it doesn't traverse visited nodes anyway, so it will still work)

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        if l is None:
            self._l = []
        else:
            self._l = l
        return

    def pop(self):
        return self._l.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self._l[-1]

    def push(self, value):
        self._l.append(value)
        return

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._l)

class NodeWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, graph, v):
        self.v = v
        self.children = Stack(graph[v])
        return

def iterative_postorder(G, s):
    onstack = [False] * len(G)
    edgeto = [None] * len(G)
    visited = [False] * len(G)

    st = Stack()
    st.push(NodeWrapper(G, s))

    while len(st) > 0:
        vnode = st.peek()
        v = vnode.v
        if not onstack[v]:
            print "Starting %d" % (v)
        visited[v] = True
        onstack[v] = True
        if len(vnode.children) > 0:
            e = vnode.children.pop()
            if onstack[e]:
                cycle = [e]
                e = v
                while e != cycle[0]:
                    cycle.append(e)
                    e = edgeto[e]
                raise StandardError("cycle detected: %s, graph not acyclic" % (cycle))
            if not visited[e]:
                edgeto[e] = v
                st.push(NodeWrapper(G, e))
        else:
            vnode = st.pop()
            onstack[vnode.v] = False
            print 'Completed %d' % (vnode.v)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for actually considering my core requirement of pre/post ops.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Node:
  def __init__( self, value ):
    self.value    = value
    self.children = []

def preprocess( node ):
  print( node.value )

def postprocess( node ):
  print( node.value )

def preorder( root ):
  # Always a flat, homogeneous list of Node instances.
  queue = [ root ]
  while len( queue ) > 0:
    a_node = queue.pop( 0 )
    preprocess( a_node )
    queue = a_node.children + queue

def postorder( root ):
  # Always a flat, homogeneous list of Node instances:
  queue   = [ root ]
  visited = set()
  while len( queue ) > 0:
    a_node = queue.pop( 0 )
    if a_node not in visited:
      visited.add( a_node )
      queue = a_node.children + [ a_node ] + queue
    else:
      # this is either a leaf or a parent whose children have all been processed
      postprocess( a_node )
```

Comment: Is it hard to make it work for a general graph DFS, rather than tree DFS? It won't work as is, since in a general graph, `a_node` may be in `visited` without being a parent.

Answer (score 3):

## Iterative solution for non-tree graphs

After unsuccessfully experimenting with different solutions, let me add pseudocode for an iterative solution where you essentially recreate the function call stack space (that could overflow in a recursive version) in a stack variable.

All the state that you need to store is the *vertex number* and the *number of neighbors already processed*. This can be a tuple, a list, an object, whatever your language allows.

The advantage of this solution is that you don't get stack overflow, **it also works for graphs having cycles** and it's pretty robust. Getting the next neighbor is easy if you use an adjacency list or matrix.

This is pseudocode because it's easier to understand, and you wouldn't just copy code from SO, would you?

```
globals: isProcessed, preOrder, postOrder

depthFirstSearch()
    set isProcessed to all false
    for each vertex
        if !isProcessed(vertex)
            explore(vertex)

explore(root)
    create stack
    add (root, 0) to stack
    visited = empty list 
        // a list of visited vertices e.g. for finding connected components

    while stack is not empty
        (vertex, processedNeighbors) ← pop from stack

        if !isProcessed(vertex)
            // previsit
            add vertex to preOrder list
            isProcessed(vertex) ← true

        if processedNeighbors < number of vertex's neighbors
            nextNeighborNumber ← processedNeighbors + 1
            push (vertex, nextNeighborNumber) to stack
            nextNeighbor ← 'nextNeighborNumber'th neighbor of vertex

            if !isProcessed(nextNeighbor)
                push (nextNeighbor, 0) to stack
        else
            // postvisit
            add vertex to postOrder list
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find it useful.

http://www.vvlasov.com/2013/07/post-order-iterative-dfs-traversal.html

Code:

```
public void dfsPostOrderIterative(AdjGraph graph, AdjGraph.Node vertex, Callback callback) {
    Stack<Level> toVisit = new Stack<Level>();
    toVisit.push(new Level(Collections.singletonList(vertex)));

    while (!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
        Level level = toVisit.peek();

        if (level.index >= level.nodes.size()) {
            toVisit.pop();
            continue;
        }

        AdjGraph.Node node = level.nodes.get(level.index);

        if (!node.isVisited()) {
            if (node.isChildrenExplored()) {
                node.markVisited();
                callback.nodeVisited(graph, node);
                level.index++;
            } else {
                List<AdjGraph.Node> edges = graph.edges(node);
                List<AdjGraph.Node> outgoing = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(edges, new Predicate<AdjGraph.Node>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(AdjGraph.Node input) {
                        return !input.isChildrenExplored();
                    }
                }));

                if (outgoing.size() > 0)
                    toVisit.add(new Level(outgoing));
                node.markChildrenExplored();
            }
        } else {
            level.index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have exactly what I need by inserting a preProcess into the postorder function provided by El Mariachi:

```
def postorder( root ):
 # Always a flat, homogeneous list of Node instances:
 queue   = [ root ]
 visited = set()
 while len( queue ) > 0:
   a_node = queue.pop( 0 )
   if a_node not in visited:
     preprocess( a_node )                  # <<<<<<<< Inserted
     visited.add( a_node )
     queue = a_node.children + [ a_node ] + queue
   else:
     # this is either a leaf or a parent whose children have all been processed
     postprocess( a_node )
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple python implementation with two different visitors

```
class Print_visitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def pre_visit(self, node):
        print "pre: ", node.value
    def post_visit(self, node):
        print "post:", node.value

class Prettyprint_visitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level=0
    def pre_visit(self, node):
        print "{}<{}>".format("    "*self.level, node.value)
        self.level += 1
    def post_visit(self, node):
        self.level -= 1
        print "{}</{}>".format("    "*self.level, node.value)

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
    def traverse(self, visitor):
        visitor.pre_visit(self)
        for child in self.children:
            child.traverse(visitor)
        visitor.post_visit(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #test
    tree = Node("root")
    tree.children = [Node("c1"), Node("c2"), Node("c3")]
    tree.children[0].children = [Node("c11"), Node("c12"), Node("c13")]
    tree.children[1].children = [Node("c21"), Node("c22"), Node("c23")]
    tree.children[2].children = [Node("c31"), Node("c32"), Node("c33")]
    tree.traverse(Print_visitor())
    tree.traverse(Prettyprint_visitor())
```

Comment: It works, but it's not iterative anymore (as asked by the author's question)

Answer (score 0):

Another variation which allows for all children nodes to be pushed on the stack at once, requiring only minimal state tracking.

Note that it produces different results from the original recursive traversal, being that it enters neighbor edges in reverse order. If this is a problem, you can reverse the neighbor list before pushing them on the stack.

```cs
private void TraverseDepthFirst(Node entryNode, Action<Node>? preVisit = null, Action<Node>? postVisit = null)
{
    var worklist = new Stack<(Node node, bool entered)>();
    var visited = new HashSet<Node>(); //not necessary for trees/acyclic-graphs.

    worklist.Push((entryNode, false));
    visited.Add(entryNode);

    while (worklist.Count > 0) {
        var (node, entered) = worklist.Pop();

        if (!entered) {
            worklist.Push((node, true));

            preVisit?.Invoke(node);

            foreach (var neighbor in node.Neighbors) {
                if (visited.Add(neighbor)) {
                    worklist.Push((neighbor, false));
                }
            }
        } else {
            postVisit?.Invoke(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution where the post-visit of a child is needed before the pre-visit of the next sibling, as mentioned by @Creak (C#):

```cpp
public void DepthFirstTraversal2(Node root)
{
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> visited = new HashSet<Node>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.TryPeek(out var node))
    {
        if (!visited.Contains(node))
        {
            visited.Add(node);
            Console.WriteLine($"Pre-visit node {node.Value}");

            foreach (Node child in node.Children)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stack.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Post-visit node {node.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```